# ClassCastException in JTable.getValueAt(...)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, classcastexception

My problem is in this code:

```
int rowToTable = table.getSelectedRow();
int bookId = (int)table.getValueAt(rowToTable, 0);  // line 158
```

What is the solution?

I need an `int` value of bookID, Not `Object`.

StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at Project.BookPage_Admin.dellAction(BookPage_Admin.java:158)
at Project.BookPage_Admin.actionPerformed(BookPage_Admin.java:126)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: what kind of objects do you have in that table?

Comment: @StefanBeike `id` , `name` , `isbn` , `borrowedStatus` and `Date` .

Comment: If you know that can be parsed to an Integer, use Integer.parseInt() over the value in the table. Or, yet better, when you create the table model, use Integer instead of String

Comment: @user3808021: Try `Integer.valueOf(table.getValueAt(rowToTable, 0)).intValue();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for sure that the content of that column is integer than instead of type casting to int just use `Integer#parseInt()`

```
 int bookId = Integer.parseInt((String)table.getValueAt(rowToTable, 0));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This one says: `incompatible types, Object cannot be converted to String`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have String values in that table.  In that case:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt((String) table.getValueAt(rowToTable, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this solution:

```
int rowToTable = table.getSelectedRow();
int bookId = Integer.valueOf((String)table.getValueAt(rowToTable, 0));
```

or

```
int bookId = Integer.parseInt((String)table.getValueAt(rowToTable, 0));
```

`valueOf` does internaly also a `parseInt`.